# Mercurial hook exited with status 1

Tags: mercurial, jenkins, hook

We use Mercurial (hg) for source control with a central repository (each developer has their own local as well). I am trying to set up a hook in the central repo such that it kicks off a Jenkins CI build.

The hook appears in the hgrc file as:

```
[hooks]
incoming.jenkins = java -jar C:/buildServerJar/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://ctc-jenkins:8080/ -i C:/buildServerJar/id_rsa build "All Working Projects"
[ui]
verbose = True
debug = True
```

Now, I have tested the command invoked from the hook on the command-line of the machine that hosts the central repository and it works as expected.

However, when I trigger the hook with a push to the central repository, I see the following output:

```
% hg --repository D:\dev\hg\******\source push W:\Repository\*********
pushing to W:\Repository\**********
searching for changes
adding changesets
add changeset 62784303122b
adding manifests
adding file changes
adding ****/CMakeLists.txt revisions
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
updating the branch cache
running hook incoming.jenkins: java -jar C:/buildServerJar/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://ctc-jenkins:8080/ -i C:/buildServerJar/id_rsa build "All Working Projects"
warning: incoming.jenkins hook exited with status 1
[command completed successfully Fri Jul 26 15:24:58 2013]
```

The server in question is a Windows machine. Any ideas what could be going wrong or how to get more details on the error?

UPDATE:

So I modified the hook to get more info:

```
incoming.jenkins = java -jar C:/buildServerJar/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://ctc-jenkins:8080/ -i C:/buildServerJar/id_rsa build "All Working Projects"  > hg_output.log 2> hg_errors.log
```

And it says it is unable to locate the jarfile, which is clearly in the location indicated. Makes me wonder if it is a permissions issue. Does anyone know what user account Mercurial runs its hooks under?

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:/buildServerJar/jenkins-cli.jar
```

Comment: It's only a guess, since you said that it is a windows machine, path in Windows should be C:\buildServerJar\jenkins-cli.jar

Comment: @cinhtau Thanks, but that's one of the first things we tried. Generally, I've found the Windows accepts both.

Comment: Did you open the cmd prompt and paste above command? What did cmd output?

Comment: @cinhtau As stated in the original question, that command works fine that way.

Comment: Check here http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html (Hooks and Security) for information on which account hooks run under.